# Cannot find module './Mime' Cuando despliego en Heroku

Tags: express, heroku, mime, despliegue

por favor su ayuda. Al tratar de desplegar mi app en Heroku me sale el siguiente error estoy utilizando excel4node en local me funciona pero al tratar de desplegar en Heroku aparece esto:[image: error en logs de Heroku]

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado, lo solucioné haciendo esto:

Primero el require de "mime" lo hice después que el require "excel4node".

Segundo dentro de mi proyecto en el archivo ubicado en la ruta `node_modules/mime/index.js`:
cambie esto: `let Mime = require('./Mime');`
por esto: `let Mime = require('./mime');`

¡Cambiando la mayúscula por la minúscula y problema solucionado!